# Dynamically create model from form builder in django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, wagtail

I have to create model from form builder. Form field as column and title as model.

is possible to implement this concept in Django?

Create dynamically model from selected field of form builder and that model register in admin.

i.g.  I have a saree as product and that contain attribute color, prize, size and then add mobile as another product that contain attribute color, prize, ram, screen_size etc. here, color and prize common field and remaining attribute different so, create two different model in django

Heartily thank you in advance !

Comment: Hi Kaushik, I just want to confirm you want to create a new Model each time, not just an entity (ie. instance of a Model in the database). This could get complex to maintain very quickly and I am not sure I could give specific advice for this scenario. It is also unclear if you are talking about Django forms or Wagtail forms? Maybe this question could get fleshed out a bit more. Anyway, maybe this might help - https://dynamic-models.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @LBBenJohnston Sir, You are understand correctly.I have to implement this in wagtail.I had [implement](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DynamicModels) and also create model but problem in migration(means how to migrate this model dynamically).If you have new idea to implement this scenario then suggest me.